# Issue run spring boot profiles jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm runing spring boot jar in a console

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev [name].jar
```

I don't understand why I get this error:

> Unable to access jarfile .profiles.active=

Comment: Is the JAR file located in the same directory from where you are trying to invoke it? You don't have to specify the jar file immediately after -jar option. Please check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html).

Answer (score 11):

For powershell, I found a solution, I put a double quote ("") `"-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"` and worked well. So the full command should be like below-

```
java -jar "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev" [name].jar
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

The line shown in the question should work. I have tried it in an own demo project: `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

So I assume @Indra Basak comment points into the correct direction. It looks as though the path to your jarfile is not correct.

Comment: I found a solution, I put quote **"-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"** and worked well

Comment: Are you using a windows Powershell to run your application. There I could reproduces your initially mentioned error. I could solve it as you mentioned with the quotes. Using the normal windows command prompt, these quotes are not necessary.

Comment: @LewisFlorezR Please post your comment as answer. I spend lots of time to find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is not correct it must be: java -jar [name].jar --spring.profiles.active=dev